# Printing XML values to a html page

Tags: java, html, json, xml, servlets

Ive created a java service which allows users to view data in either XML, Json or String. My problem is that my web page does not display the XML tags on the html page. When inspecting the element, the XML tags are there but they do not get printed to the screen. Any ideas?

Heres a screenshot and also my code.

```
public class FindStaff extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String sortedDataText = null;
    List<StaffInfo> staffInfoList = StaffUtils.findAllStaff();
    String format = request.getParameter("format");

    if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("json")) {

        sortedDataText = "{ \"membersOfStaff\":[ ";

        for (int i = 0; i < staffInfoList.size(); i++) {

            sortedDataText += "{\"id\":" + "\"" + staffInfoList.get(i).getStaffID() + "\",";
            sortedDataText += "\"forename\":" + "\"" + staffInfoList.get(i).getForename() + "\",";
            sortedDataText += "\"surname\":" + "\"" + staffInfoList.get(i).getSurname() + "\",";
            sortedDataText += "\"address\":" + "\"" + staffInfoList.get(i).getLocation() + "\",";
            sortedDataText += "\"phone\":" + "\"" + staffInfoList.get(i).getPhone() + "\",";
            sortedDataText += "\"email\":" + "\"" + staffInfoList.get(i).getEmail() + "\"}";

            if (staffInfoList.size() - i > 1) {
                sortedDataText += ",";
            }
        }

        sortedDataText += "]}";

        System.out.println("JSON DATA:  " + sortedDataText);

    } else if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("xml")) {
        sortedDataText = "<membersOfStaff>";
        for (int i = 0; i < staffInfoList.size(); i++) {

            sortedDataText += "<staffMember><id>" + staffInfoList.get(i).getStaffID() + "</id>";
            sortedDataText += "<forename>" + staffInfoList.get(i).getForename() + "</forename>";
            sortedDataText += "<surname>" + staffInfoList.get(i).getSurname() + "</surname>";
            sortedDataText += "<address>" + staffInfoList.get(i).getLocation() + "</address>";
            sortedDataText += "<phoneNumber>" + staffInfoList.get(i).getPhone() + "</phoneNumber>";
            sortedDataText += "<email>" + staffInfoList.get(i).getEmail() + "</email></staffMember>";

        }
        sortedDataText += "</membersOfStaff>";
        System.out.println("XML DATA:  " + sortedDataText);

    } else if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {

        sortedDataText = "membersOfStaff[ ";
        for (int i = 0; i < staffInfoList.size(); i++) {

            sortedDataText += "id=" + staffInfoList.get(i).getStaffID() + ",";
            sortedDataText += "forename=" + staffInfoList.get(i).getForename() + ",";
            sortedDataText += "surname=" + staffInfoList.get(i).getSurname() + ",";
            sortedDataText += "address=" + staffInfoList.get(i).getLocation() + ",";
            sortedDataText += "phoneNumber=" + staffInfoList.get(i).getPhone() + ",";
            sortedDataText += "email=" + staffInfoList.get(i).getEmail();

            if (staffInfoList.size() - i > 1) {
                sortedDataText += ", \n\n\n";
            }
        }

        sortedDataText += "]";

        System.out.println("TEXT DATA:  " + sortedDataText );
    }

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(sortedDataText);

}
```

My problem is the XML. The json data displays correctly and so does the string data..  Any ideas would be appreciated (Im new to this)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are dumping the XML output into an HTML page, the browser will not know that you have switched from HTML to XML and will treat your XML as broken HTML, which in this case seems to mean that it dumps the text from the unknown elements onto the page.

To display raw XML in an HTML page, you can programmatically escape the opening "<" characters with "<" and the "&" character with "&".

Answer (score 0):

The browser tries to render your xml. It handles everything between < and > as a tag like other html elements.
If you want to bring a < on the page, you have to escape it with &lt; or &gt;

Have a look at [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) from Apache Commons Lang